# Rails - One to one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Let's suppose that I have a list of momuments and a list of routers.
A monument has one router and a router belongs to a monument. This is a one to one relationship. The usually method to do this is to have a foreign key (monument_id) in the router table. This is pretty easy, I just need a select with the list of monuments and the association for that router is made.

But now lets suppose I want to make those assocations on the monument side. For example, I will have an `_form` for the monument and inside that form I have a select of the available routers. How can I achieve that? Because I know that will generate an error because I don't have any attribute on the monument side to save the selected router.

Is this even possible what I'm trying to accomplish? And if so, could you give me and example? Thank you!

I'm sorry about the english.

Comment: when you are creating/editing a monument, will a `router` be already present (with null `monument_id`) ?

Comment: if there is any router available, yes.

Comment: You mean this same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56009022/rails-association-on-the-side-that-hasnt-the-foreign-key ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```
def create
  monument = Monument.new(monument_params)
  if monument.save
    if router.present?
      router.monument = monument
      if router.save
        render json: monument, status: :ok
      else
        render json: router.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
      end
    else
      render json: monument, status: :ok
    end
  else
    render json: monument.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity 
  end
end

def permitted_params
  params.require(:monument).permit(:name,...,:router_id)
end

def monument_params
  permitted_params.except(:router_id)
end

def router_id
  permitted_params[:router_id]
end

def router
  if router_id
    Router.find router_id
  end
end
```

You may need to modify if your params look like this

```
params.require(:monument).permit(:name, {router_attributes: [:id]})
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the bog standard `has_one`/`belongs_to` relationship.

Both models that contain a `has_one` or `belongs_to` are *both* able to manage the relationship, and both have accessors for updating the association.

Assuming you have this...

```
class Monument
  belongs_to :router
end

class Router
  has_one :monument
end
```

Then both of these will work exactly like you would expect them to:

```
router.monument = <some monument>
```

or

```
monument.router = <some router>
```

Comment: Hi, thks for your answer. But for example if I go to the console and I do something like this: `Monument.find(1).sniffer = 1` I'll get this error: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Router(#61430480) expected, got 1 which is an instance of Fixnum`. This will work only if I give the object and not the object id, is it?

Comment: Yes, you need to assign an object on the `has_one` side of the association. Rails will handle updating the object's foreign key on the `belongs_to` side.

Comment: Humm okey thank you :) Do I need to change the monument params on monuments_controller? And if isn't asking to much could you provide me a example of the form of the monument to get the router object? I suppose is something like this: `<%= f.select ???, Router.all.collect { |s| [s.mac_address, s???]}, {}, {class:"routerSelect", include_blank: true}  %>` The `???` is where I don't know what I'm suppose to put in

Answer (score 0):

I end up solving my problem with a mix of responses, so thank you for your help.

I thought that if I add the `router_id` in the `monument_params` the rails would pick the param with the same name and would create the association by it self but, it seems out, that the Rails needs the object and not the id. So this was my solution:

- In my monument form I have a select to pick a Router

```
<%= f.select :router_id, Router.all.collect { |s| [s.mac_address, s.id]}, {}, {class:"routerSelect", include_blank: true}  %>
```

- Then in my `monuments_controller` in the create and update method I do this:

```
def create
   @monument = Monument.new(monument_params)
   @monument.router = Router.find(params[:monument][:router_id])
   if @monument.save
   ...
end

def update
   if @monument.update(monument_params)
      @monument.router = Router.find(params[:monument][:router_id])
   ...
end
```

Is not the the best solution but it solves my problem. Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be required to do `@monument.router = Router.find(params[:monument][:router_id])`. If `router_id` is whitelisted in your `monument_params`, @monument.save must do it automatically

Comment: @kiddorails if I whiteliste the `router_id` in `monument_params` I get this error: `unknown attribute 'router_id' for Monument.`

Comment: your data modelling may then have some issue later. As you said, it's 1-to-1 mapping between Router and Monument. And you are providing list of all `routers` (which may already have an associated monument with monument_id in them). With `@monument.router = ...`  you will end up overriding the associated monument on that router (if it exists)

Comment: I did a method to show only the free routers and the router already associated (if there is any). That's covered. About the modelling issue, probably there is something wrong, don't know. But for what I've search, when we create a 1-to-1 relationship and we want to make the association from the `has_on` side we need to give the object and not the object id only...